# How can I confirm a card which requires 3D Auth after a card update?

Tags: stripe-payments

When I create a subscription with stripe and the customer already has a default set payment method, I know how to confirm a card when it requires 3D Auth because I can look at the failure reason but what if a customer updates their card within the month...

How do I check if a new payment method requires 3D Auth when a customer already has an active subscription? And can I perform 3D Auth before the next subscription billing so it will work automatically without interaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a SetupIntent to attach a card to a Customer (and also perform any authentication if required), when changing a Customer's card mid-cycle.

SetupIntent's will try to claim authentication exemptions for any future off_session payments (e.g. a recurring Subscription payment). There is still a chance issuing banks might still request authentication on the recurring payment, SetupIntent just try to reduce that chance, to address your point here:

> And can I perform 3D Auth before the next subscription billing so it will work automatically without interaction?

In the case that the next recurring payment fails, you would have to bring your Customer back on session (to your payment page) and then authenticate the `subscription.latest_invoice.payment_intent.client_secret` with `confirmCardPayment()`